unique association of elements with conditions in html and php
I'm creating an interface in PHP and HTML through which the user is asked to select from three drop-down menus, an element for the morning, an element for the afternoon and an element for the evening, from a list unique.
this for 7 days.
When an item is selected, it must then disappear from the other drop-down menus.
The list is like this:

element 1
element 2
...
element 21

and this list must be associated with the day.
of the type:

day 1 morning - item 5
day 2 morning - item 7
etc. etc.

I hope I explained myself.
Can anyone tell me a method to solve this problem?
obviously if there is a simpler method to use, instead of select, I would be happy to know it.
I can't remove the selected product after the user has made the selection. in practice, after the user assigns an element to the day, that should be removed or set as non-selectable.

My code:
View:
<section class="intro container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span12">
            <p>Seleziona i piatti che vuoi inserire nel tuo menù settimanale. Puoi selezionare fino a 7 piatti per ogni pasto della giornata.</p>

            <?php
            $startDate = new DateTime($assegnazioneMemory->data);
            $endDate = new DateTime($assegnazioneMemory->data_fine);
            $endDate->modify('+1 day'); // Include the end date in the period
            $interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
            $period = new DatePeriod($startDate, $interval, $endDate);
            $numeroColazioni = new DatePeriod($startDate, $interval, $endDate);
            $giorni = array('Domenica', 'Lunedì', 'Martedì', 'Mercoledì', 'Giovedì', 'Venerdì', 'Sabato');
            ?>

            <form action="<?= base_url('questo-poi-lo-vediamo') ?>" method="post">

                <table class="table table-bordered text-center">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Giorno</th>
                            <th>Colazione</th>
                            <th>Pranzo</th>
                            <th>Cena</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <?php $i = 1; ?>
                        <?php foreach ($period as $date) :
                        ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td> <?php $dayNumber = date("w", strtotime($date->format('Y-m-d')));
                                        $dayName = $giorni[$dayNumber];
                                        $extendedDate = date("d", strtotime($date->format('Y-m-d')));
                                        echo "$dayName $extendedDate";
                                        ?>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="data<?= $i ?>" value="<?= $date->format('Y-m-d') ?>">
                                <td>
                                    <select class="form-select" id="colazione">
                                        <option selected>Seleziona colazione <?= $i ?></option>

                                        <?php
                                        $a = 0;
                                        foreach ($numeroColazioni as $giorno) {
                                            $a++; ?>
                                            <option carboidrati='
                                            <?php
                                            if (${'colazione' . $a}->alimento_1_c == 1 || ${'colazione' . $a}->alimento_2_c == 1 || ${'colazione' . $a}->alimento_3_c == 1 || ${'colazione' . $a}->alimento_4_c == 1) {
                                                echo "1";
                                            } else {
                                                echo "0";
                                            }
                                            ?>' value='<?= strval($programmaMemory->{'colazione' . $a . '_id'}) ?>'><?= strval($programmaMemory->{'colazione' . $a}) ?></option>;
                                        <?php
                                        }
                                        ?>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <select class="form-select" id="pranzo">
                                        <option selected>Seleziona pranzo <?= $i ?></option>
                                        <?php
                                        $a = 0;
                                        foreach ($numeroColazioni as $giorno) {
                                            $a++; ?>
                                            <option carboidrati='
                                            <?php
                                            if (${'pranzo' . $a}->alimento_1_c == 1 || ${'pranzo' . $a}->alimento_2_c == 1 || ${'pranzo' . $a}->alimento_3_c == 1 || ${'pranzo' . $a}->alimento_4_c == 1) {
                                                echo "1";
                                            } else {
                                                echo "0";
                                            }
                                            ?>' value='<?= strval($programmaMemory->{'pranzo' . $a . '_id'}) ?>'><?= strval($programmaMemory->{'pranzo' . $a}) ?></option>;
                                        <?php
                                        }
                                        ?>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <select class="form-select" id="cena">
                                        <option selected>Seleziona cena <?= $i ?></option>
                                        <?php
                                        $a = 0;
                                        foreach ($numeroColazioni as $giorno) {
                                            $a++; ?>
                                            <option carboidrati='
                                            <?php
                                            if (${'cena' . $a}->alimento_1_c == 1 || ${'cena' . $a}->alimento_2_c == 1 || ${'cena' . $a}->alimento_3_c == 1 || ${'cena' . $a}->alimento_4_c == 1) {
                                                echo "1";
                                            } else {
                                                echo "0";
                                            }
                                            ?>' value='<?= strval($programmaMemory->{'cena' . $a . '_id'}) ?>'><?= strval($programmaMemory->{'cena' . $a}) ?></option>;
                                        <?php
                                        }
                                        ?>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        <?php $i++;
                        endforeach;
                        ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

            </form>
        </div>

</section>


I can't remove the selected product after the user has made the selection.
in practice, after the user assigns an element to the day, that should be removed or set as non-selectable.
I have added the code written so far.

You could use htmx and apply something like this: https://v1.htmx.org/examples/value-select/ OR you have to remove/add selected items from the other dropdowns via Javascript.
